# Send image discord bot

Tags: python, image, discord, bots

Is it possible to make a command to send an image that the user chooses himself on his device?Pc or phone.It turns out to send only the images available in the root.My code always opens explorer on my PC. Whoever uses the command - the explorer opens at me. If I use the command and select an image, then the bot calmly sends it

```
import easygui
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = disnake.Intents.all())


@bot.slash_command()
async def send(ctx,*, txt, img):
    channel = get(ctx.guild.channels)
    img= easygui.fileopenbox(filetypes=[])
    await ctx.channel.send(txt, file = disnake.File(img))

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is running on your computer - so when you use `easygui` to open a file explorer; it will open on your computer. That's just how code/applications work.

However, you can use an option in your slash command to require a user to send an attachment.

```
@bot.slash_command()
async def send(ctx, text: str, image: disnake.Attachment):
    _file = await image.to_file()
    await ctx.send(content=text, file=_file)
```

[Docs are disnake.Attachment](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.Attachment). We can use the [`to_file`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.Attachment.to_file) method to convert the attachment to a [`disnake.File`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.File), which we can pass directly in to [`ctx.send`](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.ApplicationCommandInteraction.send). Using `send` here prevents the interaction giving us a "interaction failed" message in Discord.